# Link clang++ modules: Function exported using C++20 modules is not visible (clang++): Cannot compile executable file that uses module

Tags: c++20, clang++, c++-modules

I am exporting a function in the following C++20 module. Although the main program can import the module, but it cannot see the exported function:

f1.hpp

```cpp
export module f1_module;
export void f1() {
}
```

f1_demo.cpp

```cpp
import f1_module;
int main() {
   f1();
   return 0;
}
```

The build script is:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
mkdir -p ./target

FLAGS="-std=c++20 -stdlib=libc++ -fmodules -fbuiltin-module-map"

clang++ $FLAGS \
    -fprebuilt-module-path=./target \
    -Xclang -emit-module-interface  \
    -c \
    f1.hpp \
    -o ./target/f1.module.o

clang++ $FLAGS \
    -fprebuilt-module-path=./target \
        -fmodule-file=f1_module=./target/f1.module.o \
    f1_demo.cpp \
    -o ./target/f1_demo.o
```

The output error: `bash build.bash`:

```
ld: error: undefined symbol: f1()
>>> referenced by f1_demo.cpp
>>>               /tmp/f1_demo-286314.o:(main)
clang-14: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The exported function `f1()` is not visible in the main program. How to make it work?

I can provide the output to `-v`.

I am running above build script in `conanio/clang14` docker container:

```bash
docker run -it --rm -v $(pwd):/sosi conanio/clang14-ubuntu16.04:latest  bash
```

#### Update: Cannot link

I tried @DavisHerring 's suggestion, adding `-c` to the second command, however, it does not generate executable. What I have is a regular object file, and a compiled module file. (The outcome of of `-c` is not executable). But I need an executable: I cannot link them. When tried to link using clang++, the problem is about linking:

I cannot link an object file with a compiled module file:

```
clang++ $FLAGS \
    -Xclang -emit-module-interface  \
    -c \
    f1_module.cpp \
    -o ./target/f1_module.o

clang++ $FLAGS \
    -fmodule-file=f1_module=./target/f1_module.o \
    -c \
    f1_demo.cpp \
    -o ./target/f1_demo.o

clang \
    -v \
    ./target/f1_module.o \
    ./target/f1_demo.o \
    -o ./target/exe.o
```

output:

```
"/usr/local/bin/ld" -z relro --hash-style=gnu --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -o ./target/exe.e /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o /usr/local/lib/clang/14.0.0/lib/linux/clang_rt.crtbegin-x86_64.o -L/usr/local/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10.3.0 -L/usr/local/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10.3.0/../../../../lib64 -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/local/bin/../lib -L/usr/local/bin/../lib64 -L/lib -L/usr/lib ./target/f1_module.module ./target/f1_demo.o /usr/local/lib/clang/14.0.0/lib/linux/libclang_rt.builtins-x86_64.a --as-needed -l:libllvm-unwind.so --no-as-needed -lc /usr/local/lib/clang/14.0.0/lib/linux/libclang_rt.builtins-x86_64.a --as-needed -l:libllvm-unwind.so --no-as-needed /usr/local/lib/clang/14.0.0/lib/linux/clang_rt.crtend-x86_64.o /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
```

followed by error: **unclosed quote**

```
ld: error: ./target/f1_module.o:1427: unclosed quote
clang-14: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Note: I am running it on MacBook M1 (arm64) with MacOS Monterey 12.4 and run `clang++` via Docker 4.9.1 ( Engine: 20.10.16 ).

Comment: Yes, I have tried that too. Let me double check.

Comment: Yes, it didn't help. I amended the question to export the definition too.

Comment: You’re missing the `-c` for the second compilation, so it’s trying to link before you’ve supplied the object file from the module unit.

Comment: But I want to create an executable file. If I specify `-c` it will not generate an executable. Do you mean I need to link it in a separate command?

Comment: You need to provide the module’s `.o` file when making the executable (which generally shouldn’t itself end with `.o`), whether that’s in the same command (without `-c`) or in a follow-up `ld` command.  There **may** be a subtlety with `-emit-module-interface` combining with `-o` in the first line.

Comment: Thank you. I changed the file extensions from `.o` but didn't work.

Comment: It tried to run a long `ld` command which I just added to the question description.

Comment: I think your solution works, but it has to be on a native amd64 / x86_64 with Linux. 

I am running it on MacBook M1 with MacOS Monterey 12.4 with Docker 4.9.1 ( Engine: 20.10.16 ). When I ran it on a native x86_64 with Docker on Linux, it works. Please post your comment as answer so that I can accept the answer. Your comments helped leading me to the solution. Docker does not fully support emulating x86_64 / amd64 on arm machines.

Comment: The solution I provided in the question works. It was the incompatible CPU architecture ( arm64 ) issue that caused the error. Corrected by switching to Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to compile a module **twice**. Once to emit a module interface file (which should **not** have the .o suffix BTW; the customary suffix is .pcm, for "precompiled module") and once to emit an object file (with the customary .o suffix).

```
clang++ -std=c++20 -c f1_module.cpp -o target/f1_module.o # plain old object
clang++ -std=c++20 -Xclang -emit-module-interface \
      -c f1_module.cpp -o target/f1_module.pcm # module interface
```

Now your module (consisting of **two** files) is ready, you can use it.

You need to **compile** the main file against the .pcm file and **link** the resulting objects against the .o file to produce an executable.

```
clang++ -std=c++20 -fprebuilt-module-path=./target \
      -c f1_demo.cpp -o target/f1_demo.o
clang++ -std=c++20 target/f1_demo.o target/f1_module.o -o target/f1.exe
```

This is not *strictly* necessary. With clang, the precompiled module *can* be used as an object file. The linker however won't recognize it, so clang will need to convert .pcm to .o and feed the temporary .o to the linker, each time you link. This is somewhat of a waste so you may want to eliminate this conversion step by building a separate .o file as above. If you choose not to, you still need to mention the module file on the link line. The simplified process is like this:

```
clang++ -std=c++20 -Xclang -emit-module-interface \
      -c f1_module.cpp -o target/f1_module.pcm # compile module once
clang++ -std=c++20 -fprebuilt-module-path=./target \
      -c f1_demo.cpp -o target/f1_demo.o # compile main just as before
clang++ -std=c++20 target/f1_demo.o target/f1_module.pcm \
      -o target/f1.exe # mention .pcm explicitly
```

As far as I know (and I don't know very much), there is currently no way to have clang find out automatically which modules to link against.

Comment: So, are you saying linking is possible in both ways: (1) `f1_module.pcm`+`f1_demo.o`  and (2) `f1_module.o`+`f1_demo.o` ? Then  why are you suggesting compiling twice and generating both  `f1_module.o` and  `f1_module.pcm`?

Comment: To eliminate a conversion at every link.

Comment: I thought the bounty is assigned (it showed it on your answer) but then it just told me the bounty is expired. I wanted to add a new bounty and give it but now the bounties it show me are too high ( +200 at least)

Comment: @SohailSi no worries, it's all just Internet score points.